# Display comma separated values for non existing rows in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the below Dataset which looks like this.

```
t               mean        max     min     std     data_id
4/14/2010 0:00  12.6941 12.6941 12.6941 12.6941          1
4/14/2010 0:00  12.3851 12.3851 12.3851 12.3851          2
4/14/2010 0:20  12.389  12.389  12.389  12.389           1
4/14/2010 0:20  12.1836 12.1836 12.1836 12.1836          2
4/14/2010 0:20  11.3887 11.3887 11.3887 11.3887          4
```

I want to transform the data to

```
t,str_agg
'2010-04-14 00:00:00','12.6941','12.6941','12.6941','12.6941','12.3851','12.3851','12.3851','12.3851',,,,
'2010-04-14 00:10:00','12.3890','12.3890','12.3890','12.3890','12.1836','12.1836','12.1836','12.1836','11.3887','11.3887','11.3887','11.3887
```

I have tried the below query:-

```
WITH dataset AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM
        (
            VALUES
            ('2010-04-14T00:00'::TIMESTAMP, 12.6941, 12.6941, 12.6941, 12.6941, 1),
            ('2010-04-14T00:00'::TIMESTAMP, 12.3851, 12.3851, 12.3851, 12.3851, 2),
            ('2010-04-14T00:20'::TIMESTAMP, 12.389, 12.389, 12.389, 12.389, 1),
            ('2010-04-14T00:20'::TIMESTAMP, 12.1836, 12.1836, 12.1836, 12.1836, 2),
            ('2010-04-14T00:20'::TIMESTAMP, 11.3887, 11.3887, 11.3887, 11.3887, 13)
        ) AS data(t, mean, max, min, std, data_id)
),
dataset_full AS (
    SELECT
        coalesce(t, time) AS t,
        mean,
        max,
        min,
        std,
        data_id
    FROM
        generate_series(
                (SELECT min(t) FROM dataset),
                (SELECT max(t) FROM dataset),
                '10 minutes')
            AS times(time)
        CROSS JOIN generate_series(
                       (SELECT min(data_id) FROM dataset),
                       (SELECT max(data_id) FROM dataset))
            AS data_id(id)
        LEFT JOIN dataset ON times.time = dataset.t AND data_id.id = dataset.data_id
)
SELECT
    t,
    string_agg(concat(mean, ',', max, ',', min, ',', std), ',')
FROM dataset_full
GROUP BY t
ORDER BY t;
```

And i get the below result :-

```
'2010-04-14 00:00:00','12.6941,12.6941,12.6941,12.6941,12.3851,12.3851,12.3851,12.3851,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,'
'2010-04-14 00:10:00',',,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,'
'2010-04-14 00:20:00','12.389,12.389,12.389,12.389,12.1836,12.1836,12.1836,12.1836,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,11.3887,11.3887,11.3887,11.3887'
```

But i want the below result :-

```
'2010-04-14 00:00:00','12.6941,12.6941,12.6941,12.6941,12.3851,12.3851,12.3851,12.3851,,,,'
'2010-04-14 00:20:00','12.389,12.389,12.389,12.389,12.1836,12.1836,12.1836,12.1836,11.3887,11.3887,11.3887,11.3887'
```

Can anyone please help me in resolving the above issue!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your basic problem is that you are generating the time intervals and data set ids rather than reading them from the data.  This affects the `dataset_full` CTE.  You seem to want only the values that are somewhere in the data.

Hence:

```
with dataset as (
      select *
      from (values ('2010-04-14T00:00'::TIMESTAMP, 12.6941, 12.6941, 12.6941, 12.6941, 1),
                   ('2010-04-14T00:00'::TIMESTAMP, 12.3851, 12.3851, 12.3851, 12.3851, 2),
                   ('2010-04-14T00:20'::TIMESTAMP, 12.389, 12.389, 12.389, 12.389, 1),
                   ('2010-04-14T00:20'::TIMESTAMP, 12.1836, 12.1836, 12.1836, 12.1836, 2),
                   ('2010-04-14T00:20'::TIMESTAMP, 11.3887, 11.3887, 11.3887, 11.3887, 13)
           ) AS data(t, mean, max, min, std, data_id)
      ),
     dataset_full as (
       select t.t, d.data_id,
              ds.mean, ds.max, ds.min, ds.std
       from (select distinct t from dataset) t cross join
            (select distinct data_id from dataset) d left join
            dataset ds
            on ds.t = t.t and ds.data_id = d.data_id
     )
select t,string_agg(concat(mean, ',', max, ',', min, ',', std), ',' order by data_id)
from dataset_full
group by t
order by t;
```

[Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!15/9eecb7db59d16c80417c72d1e1f4fbf1/22867) is the SQL Fiddle.

Also note the `order by` in the `string_agg()`.  Presumably, you want these values in the order of `dataset_id`.

Answer (score 0):

You could replace `LEFT JOIN` with `JOIN`:

```
WITH dataset AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM(VALUES
     ('2010-04-14T00:00'::TIMESTAMP, 12.6941, 12.6941, 12.6941, 12.6941, 1),
     ('2010-04-14T00:00'::TIMESTAMP, 12.3851, 12.3851, 12.3851, 12.3851, 2),
     ('2010-04-14T00:20'::TIMESTAMP, 12.389, 12.389, 12.389, 12.389, 1),
     ('2010-04-14T00:20'::TIMESTAMP, 12.1836, 12.1836, 12.1836, 12.1836, 2),
     ('2010-04-14T00:20'::TIMESTAMP, 11.3887, 11.3887, 11.3887, 11.3887, 13)
     ) AS data(t, mean, max, min, std, data_id)
),
dataset_full AS (
    SELECT coalesce(t, time) AS t,
        mean,
        max,
        min,
        std,
        data_id
    FROM generate_series(
                (SELECT min(t) FROM dataset),
                (SELECT max(t) FROM dataset),
                '10 minutes')
            AS times(time)
        CROSS JOIN generate_series(
                       (SELECT min(data_id) FROM dataset),
                       (SELECT max(data_id) FROM dataset))
            AS data_id(id)
        JOIN dataset    -- here
          ON times.time = dataset.t 
         AND data_id.id = dataset.data_id
)
SELECT t,string_agg(concat(mean, ',', max, ',', min, ',', std), ',')
FROM dataset_full
GROUP BY t
ORDER BY t;
```

**[DBFiddle Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=a18ffeea1006cbc70bc58221374cd0fb)**

**EDIT:**

> *The ,,,, in the first line is getting deleted which i do not want*

```
...
 cte2 AS (
  SELECT    t,   string_agg(concat(mean, ',', max, ',', min, ',', std), ',') AS s
       , COUNT(*) AS c
  FROM dataset_full
  GROUP BY t
)
SELECT t, s|| REPEAT(',,,,', (MAX(c) OVER() - c)::int)
FROM cte2
ORDER BY t;
```

**[DBFiddle Demo2](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=e7a202851fe50f6cffeb1e6760b6e4e4)**

Output:

```
┌─────────────────────┬─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ t                   │ result                                                                                      │
├─────────────────────┼─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ 2010-04-14 00:00:00 │ 12.6941,12.6941,12.6941,12.6941,12.3851,12.3851,12.3851,12.3851,,,,                         │
│ 2010-04-14 00:20:00 │ 12.389,12.389,12.389,12.389,12.1836,12.1836,12.1836,12.1836,11.3887,11.3887,11.3887,11.3887 │
└─────────────────────┴─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

Comment: In that case i am getting the below result:- '2010-04-14 00:00:00','12.6941,12.6941,12.6941,12.6941,12.3851,12.3851,12.3851,12.3851'
'2010-04-14 00:20:00','12.389,12.389,12.389,12.389,12.1836,12.1836,12.1836,12.1836,11.3887,11.3887,11.3887,11.3887' ...  The ,,,, in the first line is getting deleted which i do not want

Comment: @Sunny Easy to fix